# How to add script link in magento page?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, page, prototype-js

I have added one script in the form page which is,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.removeOnFocus').each(function()
{
    this.data = new Object(); //TODO don't overwrite previous data
    this.data.value = this.value;

    $(this).focus(function(){
        if (this.value == this.data.value)
            this.value = '';
    });
    $(this).blur(function(){
        if (this.value == '')
            this.value = this.data.value;
    });
});
});
</script>
```

To make this script working, I have added `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the same page. Its working fine but other contents in the page getting overlapping. How to avoid this and have to make this script?

Comment: Try to put your script in the footer of the page and see if it works fine.

Comment: Its not working. Whether I need to add the supporting script link in same page or without adding it will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is a Jquery script : so you have to include it if you want your script to work.

If you don't want to include Jquery, you will have to rewrite your script using Prototype.

Finally, if you prefer to use JQuery, there will be a conflict between Jquery and Prototype for the symbol `$` : try to replace `$` by `jQuery` in your script.

To go further, you may want to try [JQuery NoConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) .